QuickGrid Blazor .NET 8 - wordwrap title to next line
I want to use QuickGrid with Blazor on .NET 8. I have columns with small digit data, but long titles to describe the data properly.
At the moment, if I want the title to be displayed, I need to make the column as wide as the title. This wastes a lot of screen space. I want to make the title appear on two lines.
I tried every word wrap option in CSS, but none work.
Any clues or ideas?
Thanks!

UPDATE
Here I got a feasible styling.
You can keep using PropertyColumn only, and need only the setting in app.css.
.quickgrid[theme=TooLong] .col-title-text {
    width: 250px;
    /*This two core settings*/
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You are not describing your question clearly, I'll show you a sample.
Based on my project, you might apply QuickGrid like this:
<QuickGrid Items="data" Theme="TooLong">
    <PropertyColumn Title="This is a very very very long title of the first column" Property="@(item => item.PropertyA)" Class="TTTitle">
    </PropertyColumn>
    <PropertyColumn Title="Another Long Title That Needs Wrapping" Property="@(item => item.PropertyB)" Class="TTTitle">
    </PropertyColumn>
</QuickGrid>

And the column acts like you described, being too long and won't wrap even with length configured.

Solution
1. You could add the HeaderTemplate to make it wrap automatically.
<QuickGrid Items="data" Theme="TooLong">
    <PropertyColumn Title="Title1" Property="@(item => item.PropertyA)" Class="TTTitle">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="header">This is a very long title that needs to wrap</div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
    </PropertyColumn>
    <PropertyColumn Title="Title2" Property="@(item => item.PropertyB)" Class="TTTitle">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="header">Another very long title that needs to wrap</div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
    </PropertyColumn>
</QuickGrid>

I start the with a default BlazorWeb App .net8 and latest package of  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid. And you can see that it will wrap automatically.

In app.css I set the length, two ways both ok
.quickgrid[theme=TooLong] > thead .TTTitle {
    width: 250px;
}

.quickgrid .col-header-content {
    width: 250px;
}

2. What's More
There is another design, you could dynamically adjust the width of title during the app is running. Also based on the usage of HeaderTemplate.
drag to adjust the width


Thank you very much for your help. I was able to wrap my titles on a second line using the  option.
What I like about Quickgrid are its built in features. The thing is, I can no longer use the Sortable="true" option in the PopertyColumn.
Image Example

Code Example

@sTaLa Yes I tested with the issue and it's true, adding the HeadTemplate makes the Sortable stop working. At present there is a way to use TemplateColumn introduced in the doc  https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/sample  However this method is designed for more complex entity using scenarios and coding being not so clean and clear.  Adjusting the css will affect the style but cannot cover, which needs more research.

@sTaLa I have figured out a solution , you could check if it work for your scenario.
